# Sending group custom attributes through the Okta SCIM app

Tags: okta, provisioning, scim

Trying to create a SCIM application in Okta that would provision both users and groups.
Users seem to work as expected and I am able to push custom attributes for users to our app and also do the proper mappings.

However, I have some issues with Groups. I am using Push Group mechanism.

After I enabled the feature called **Group Profiles for Universal Directory** an Okta Group Profile was added to the Directory -> Profile Editors, to which I added some new attributes for groups (e.g. email, okta id).
If I create groups with these custom attributes and push them, the only information I get sent to our app is displayName and members.
This is the POST body:

```
{"schemas":["urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:core:2.0:Group"],"displayName":"name of group","members":[]}
```

So no email or other custom attributes.

It is not clear to me how to differentiate our SCIM app attributes for users vs the ones for groups. In the attribute mappings I only see “From Okta **user** to My app”, and no “From Okta **group** to My app” and I can only choose user.attribute and not group.attribute.

Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: Did you ever find a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer from support saying that provisioning through SCIM custom group attributes is not supported yet. The option might be available later this year, but there is no ETA.